# Why stack-based value type fields are guaranteed to be zero?

Tags: c#, .net

Please note that, this question is NOT the the same as "Why do local variables require initialization, but fields do not?" or "Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?".
Let's say we have the following code:

```
struct MyStruct {
   int num;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyStruct m = new MyStruct();
    Console.WriteLine(m.num);    // display 0
}
```

We can see that the when we use new `new MyStruct()`, default parameterless constructor invokes, which initializs its field to their default value(0 in this case).

Buf if we do:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyStruct m;
    Console.WriteLine(m.num);    // compile error
}
```

This code doesn't compile because we have to assign a value to the struct's fields before we can use them. This mean when we just declare a struct `MyStruct m;`, the struct's default constructor won't be called, which means that the stack just gets decremented by size of `m` (allocate space for `m`). When stack gets decremented, the space can contain any value (e.g values left by previous stack operations)

But if I put a breakpoint:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyStruct m;
                    <------------ breakpoint here
    ...
}
```

and run the debug mode, when the mouse hovers over on `m`, I can clearly see that `m.num` is 0, it is always zero no matter how many time I try.

How come it is always zero? Does CLR initialize the new allocated content of stack to be 0? if CLR does initialize it to 0, then that means `MyStruct m;` is equivalent to  `MyStruct m = new MyStruct();`, Then why Microsoft team doesn't make `MyStruct m;` the same as `MyStruct m = new MyStruct();`?

Comment: Yes, the CLR initialises the stack area to zero. Note that .Net 5 introduces a way to turn this off: See [`SkipLocalsInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.skiplocalsinitattribute?view=net-5.0), and also [more info here](https://www.meziantou.net/csharp-9-improve-performance-using-skiplocalsinit.htm)

Comment: Yes, runtime guarantee.  Languages that don't have C#'s *definite assignment* feature take advantage of zero-initialization as well.  The difference is a simple side-effect of the C# implementation not being perfect, the compiler doesn't try to decide what happens in another method.  Beyond the halting problem issues, it often just doesn't know because the method lives in a different assembly.

Comment: @Matthew Watson thanks for your answer. Then why Microsoft team doesn't make `MyStruct m;` the same as `MyStruct m = new MyStruct();`?

Comment: `why Microsoft team doesn't make MyStruct m; the same as MyStruct m = new MyStruct()` Because there are instances where you want to declare a struct separately from initialising it, and you don't want to pay the cost of initialising it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happens with integers and other built-ins; consider local variable `int x`. The C# spec mandates that it must be assigned prior to use, but the IL initializes it to 0.

*Verifiable* IL (which is what C# produces unless you use an "unsafe" feature like pointers or the SkipLocalsInit feature Matthew Watson mentioned) guarantees the locals are zeroed out at method startup.
I'd guess this is because if the locals weren't zeroed, they could contain arbitrary data (whatever happened to be on the call stack prior to adding the current method's frame), which would hinder the JITter's safety guarantees.
Otherwise, the JITter would also have to do some kind of definite assignment analysis itself, which would be an unnecessary cost if high-level languages are already going to guarantee it.

C# has an additional rule that says local variables must be definitely assigned prior to use. This extends to fields of value-type variables.

(I'll add that this feature has been helpful to me in the past: if I have a method that returns a struct, and I start the method off with a local variable that I return at the end of the method, then I can use this compiler check to guarantee all code paths through the method fully populate the struct.)

So you're right in that at runtime `MyStruct m;` and `MyStruct m = new MyStruct();` will both lead to `m` being zeroed-out. The difference is that C# enforces an additional compile-time requirement.

As to *why* there is this difference, that's a matter of language design. IL is intended to be quickly understood and compiled by the JITter, so fewer / simpler rules makes that job easier. But C# is intended to help developers write programs, and checking that a local is assigned before access is apparently worth the cost of the compile time check to ensure developers don't forget to intentionally give value type variables a value before using them.